# How do I make a correct Loop Syntax?

Tags: python, fastapi

```py
@app.get("/get-by-author")
def book(name: str):
    for author in books:
        if books[author]["name"] == name:
            return books[author]
    return {"Data": "Not found"}
```

This is for fastapi query parameters.
I have tried rewriting the loop but it keeps telling me the same error.

Comment: Please update your question with the text of the full error traceback.

Comment: Also include `books`.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki tbh, `author in books` and `books[author]` is a rather unlikely pairing. So that "only" may be a bit generous.

Answer (score 2):

When doing a `for a in b` loop, you can access element `a` directly.
Corrected version (making heavy assumptions about your previous code since you have not included it):

```
@app.get("/get-by-author")
def book(name: str):
    for author in books:
        if author["name"] == name:
            return author
    return {"Data": "Not found"}
```

Comment: Now the only question that remains is why a list of books contains authors.

Comment: I agree. Likely the variable naming is a bit unorthodox

Comment: @Matthias I have another question: How do you know it's a list and not a dict?

Comment: Like I said, I made heavy assumptions about his code. Likely the problem is already answered in the first sentence of my answer, the code sample should help understand and fix the issue.

Comment: *"made heavy assumptions about his code"* - Why, though? Just wait for them to provide the missing information (ask for more if the existing requests don't suffice).

Comment: You are correct, maybe my answer was prematurely written. My initial thought was that I could maybe solve the issue even without knowing the full details of his code. I will update my answer accordingly when/if the question is updated.

Comment: @Quantum Yes, premature, as you even knew you were making heavy assumptions. And it's problematic *even if you're right*, as plenty of askers don't fix their question once they get what they want (or *think* they got it... I've seen people *accept* completely *wrong* answers because they didn't understand them). In which case the question remains broken, which is bad.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways that you can loop in python.
The first one is **use range function with length function**, you can access the books element by using the index.

```html
@app.get("/get-by-author")
def book(name: str):
    for inded in range(len(books)):
        if books[index]["name"] == name:
            return books[index]["author"]
    return {"Data": "Not found"}
```

The second one is use **for book in books** directly, which loop the every object inside the list. You are recommended to use this method for this case.

```html
@app.get("/get-by-author")
def book(name: str):
    for author in books:
        if author["name"] == name:
            return author
    return {"Data": "Not found"}
```